# Hyperbolic translation

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, reflection

I've been working on the following problem, and although I've made some progress, I don't know how to finish. Throughout the exercise, we are working in the Poincaré disc.

Consider the points $p=(-1/3,0)$ and $q==(1/3,2/3)$, and let $T$ be the hyperbolic translation such that $T(p)=q$. Let $R$ be the hyperbolic rotation around $p$ in $\pi/2$. Determine if $TR$ is a hyperbolic translation, rotation or parallel displacement.

Progress so far: The translation $T$ takes a point and sends it to another point that lies on the Euclidean circle that passes through the point and the points $(\frac{-12\sqrt{13}-15}{61},\frac{-10\sqrt{13}+18}{61})$ and $(\frac{12\sqrt{13}-15}{61},\frac{10\sqrt{13}+18}{61})$. I did this by a direct computation, by finding the hyperbolic line that goes through $p$ and $q$ and seeing where it intersects the unit circle. Next, the rotation around $p$ in $\pi/2$ is the composition of two reflections, one with respect to the line $y=0$ and the other one with respect to the circle $(x+5/3)^2+(y-4/3)^2=32/9$. I also did this by direct computation.

Now, in order to see what $TR$ is, I believe I would want to be looking for fixed points, for example. However, the only way I can think of doing this is by explicitly writing out the formula for $TR$. This doesn't seem elegant or desirable. Can anyone help me?

$^*$I recently posted this accidentally using someone else's account that also uses this computer; I deleted that question and am asking it again.

Comment: I assume the coordinates/equations in your post referring to points inside the unit disc model of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: Yes! I'll edit the question.

Comment: This can be proved in a purely "synthetic" fashion, using neutral geometry axioms/theorems (meaning axioms/theorems that are satisfied by both Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry). Would an answer like that be satisfactory to you?

Comment: @LeeMosher I would most certainly be interested in an answer like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm also very curious how this can be solved using neutral geometry, since the answer depends on the hyperbolic distance between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, because I misread the post: I read the angle as $\pi$ instead of $\pi/2$.

Comment: Defining $T$ as "the hyperbolic translation such that $T(p)=q$" isn't unique. My guess would be that this is intended to be the translation that fixes the line (i.e. geodesic) connecting $p$ and $q$, but the wording doesn't say so. There is a family of translations matching the wording, parameterized by two real degrees of freedom, e.g. representing the ideal fixed points of the translation.

Comment: I take back the claimed two real degrees of freedom; there is only one. I also failed to mention that your work so far followed my guessed interpretation of fixing that line, so most likely my two comments have little practical impact on your task, unless my guess is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've been able to work it out. Here's the answer (I've omitted many of the explicit calculations since they are fairly easy and a bit tedious to write out):

The hyperbolic line that goes through $p$ and $q$ has equation $N:(x+5/3)^2+(y-2)^2=\frac{52}{9}$. The hyperbolic line that goes through $p$ and is orthogonal to this circle has equation $M:(x+5/3)^2+(y+8/9)^2=208/81$, and by an explicit calculation we find that the translation $T$ can be obtained by reflecting around the circle $L:(x+5)^2+(y+14/3)^2=25+14^2/9-1$ and then reflecting around $M$.

Now to calculate the rotation around $p$, let $K$ be the circle $(x+5/3)^2+(y+4/15)^2=25/9+16/15^2-1$. This circle passes through $p$ and intersects $M$ in an angle of $\pi/4$. Therefore, rotation around $p$ in $\pi/4$ can be calculated by reflecting first around $K$ and then $M$. Therefore, $TR$ can be obtained by reflecting first around $K$, then $M$, then $M$ and finally $L$. In particular, this is equal to reflecting around $K$ and then $L$. Since $K$ and $L$ are disjoint, we obtain that $TR$ is a **translation**.

I hope this makes sense.